# Searching through a multi-branch graph and returning a path [C#]

Tags: search, graph, path-finding

In my situation I have territory objects. Each territory knows what other territories they are connected to through an array. Here is an visualization of said territories as they would appear on a map:

[image]

If you were to map out the connections on a graph, they would look like this:

[image]

So say I have a unit stationed in territory `[b]` and I want to move it to territory `[e]`, I'm looking for a method of searching through this graph and returning a final array that represents the path my unit in territory `[b]` must take. In this scenario, I would be looking for it to return

```
[b, e].
```

If I wanted to go from territory `[a]` to territory `[f]` then it would return:

```
[a, b, e, f].
```

I would love examples, but even just posts pointing me in the right direction are appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of Breadth-First Search (BFS) before?

Basically, you simply put your initial territory, "a" in your example, into an otherwise empty queue Q

The second data structure you need is an array of booleans with as many elements as you have territories, in this case 9. It helps with remembering which territories we have already checked. We call it V (for "visited"). It needs to be initialized as follows: All elements equal false except the one corresponding to the initial square. That is for all territories t, we have V[t] = false, but V[a] = true because "a" is already in the queue.

The third and final data structure you need is an array to store the parent nodes (i.e. which node we are coming from). It also has as many elements as you have territories. We call it P (for "parent") and every element points to itself initially, that is for all t in P, set P[t] = t.

Then, it is quite simple:

```
while Q is not empty:
   t = front element in the queue (remove it also from Q)
   if t = f we can break from while loop //because we have found the goal
   for all neighbors s of t for which V[s] = false:
       add s into the back of Q //we have never explored the territory s yet as V[s] = false
       set V[s] = true //we do not have to visit s again in the future

       //we found s because there is a connection from t to s
       //therefore, we need to remember that in s we are coming from the node t
       //to do this we simply set the parent of s to t:
       P[s] = t
```

How do you read the solution now?

Simply check the parent of f, then the parent of that and then the parent of that and so on until you find the beginning. You will know what the beginning is once you have found an element which has itself as the parent (remember that we let them point to itself initially) or you can also just compare it to a.
Basically, you just need a empty list L, add f into it and then

```
while f != a:
    f = P[f]
    add f into L
```

Note that this obviously fails if there exists no path because f will never equal a.
Therefore, this:

```
while f != P[f]:
    f = P[f]
    add f into L
```

is a bit nicer. It exploits the fact that initially all territories point to themselves in P.

If you try this on paper with you example above, then you will end up with
L = [f, e, b, a]
If you simply reverse this list, then you have what you wanted.

I don't know C#, so I didn't bother to use C# syntax. I assume that you know it is easiest to index your territories with integers and then use an array to access them.

You will realize quite quickly why this works. It's called breadth-first search because you consider only neighbors of the territory "a" first, with trivially shortest path to them (only 1 edge) and only once you processed all these, then territories that are further away will appear in the queue (only 2 edges from the start now) and so on. This is why we use a queue for this task and not something like a stack.

Also, this is linear in the number of territories and edges because you only need to look at every territory and edge (at most) once (though edges from both directions).

The algorithm I have given to you is basically the same as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search with only the P data structure added to keep track where you are coming from to be able to figure out the path taken.

Comment: This is a fantastic response and I just wanted to thank you for it! I will try this method out this weekend and get back to you.

Comment: You're welcome! Let us know if you run into any difficulties.

Comment: Okay, I know this is a bit late but I just got time to implement this and wanted to follow up. Things are working mostly correct, however I have a feeling I didn't quite do things correctly. When I try to do something like `[f]` to `[b]` everything works fine and it returns the correct path, however if I try something like `[g]` to `[a]` I get an infinite loop and hang. I'm sure it's just a simple case of misunderstanding something you wrote.

Here's what I've written: https://pastebin.com/03PWRu9h

With this being my territory class: https://pastebin.com/sq0viDwb

Comment: Sorry for the late reply from my side as well. I have taken a quick look at the code and line 49 seems to be in the wrong location where you set `s.parent = t;` You do it every time you are iterating through the neighbors, but you should only do it when you actually find `s` the first time. The solution should be to simply move line 49 right below line 36 into the if branch.